# SwiftUI - Reload views when language changes

Tags: ios, swiftui

In my app the user can change the language using a picker, and this selected language gets stored to UserDefaults.

Then, in the SwiftUI Views, I'm using this method to get the localized strings translated:

```
public static func localizedBasedSelectedLanguage(key: String, bundle: Bundle =  Bundle.main) -> String? {
    // Get the correct language bundle
    let bundlePath = bundle.path(forResource: locale.identifier, ofType: "lproj")!
    let bundle = Bundle(path: bPath)!

    // Return the translated string using the language bundle.
    return bundle.localizedString(forKey: key, value: "", table: nil)
}
```

The problem I have is when the user change the language, the screens remain localized in the old language until they are refreshed.

I have been able to force the screen to refresh by adding a reference to the AppStorage:

```
    @AppStorage("localIdentifier") private var localIdentifier: String = ""
```

And adding an empty `onChange`:

```
.onChange(of: localIdentifier) { _ in
    // Adding this forces the screen to reload when the localIdentifier changes
}
```

However, in order for this to work properly, this `AppStorage` and `onChange` need to be added to all the screens, which is quite annoying.

Is there a better way to force all screens to reload when the language changes?

Comment: In general it is not a good idea to implement language selection in your app. The user can select a language for your app in the settings app. Changing this will automatically restart your app and you can take care of automatic localisation.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, I agree on that. But due to the characteristics of the app it is not an option to handle the languages from settings.

Comment: Have you tried putting the app storage at the root and making the value the id? This will redraw your entire app. Might lead to their undesired behaviors too. But depending on the setup it might work.

Comment: @loremipsum I did try putting the AppStorage at the MainApp (root), but it didn't work. I don't fully get what you mean by "making the value the id" though...

Comment: Add “.id(localIdentifier)” to the ContentView in the App file. localIdentifier being an AppStorage

Comment: Thanks @loremipsum. It does have some side effects using this id. But I think I can get this working using this approach.

Comment: [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/restoring_your_app_s_state_with_swiftui) might help with some of the side effects

Comment: @nikano did you manage to work it somehow?